# How to make a dragable widget scalable?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

In Flutter, how do you make a widget scaleable and dragable at the same time?

A `GestureDetector`, for some reason, behaves a little strange. For example:

```
return GestureDetector(
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalScroll,
  onScaleUpdate: onScale,
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: SomeCustomPainter( /* some parameters */ ),
  ),
);
```

The above `GestureDetector` is placed somewhere deep down inside a `SingleChildScrollView`.
Problem is that `onHorizontalScroll` triggers most of the time when `onScale` is supposed to trigger.
In which case (about 9 out of 10 times) the widget doesn't scale.
The only way to reliably make the widget scalable is by removing `onHorizontalDargUpate`, but then it can't be dragged any more...

So the question now is, how do you make a widget dragable and scalable at the same time? Any advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `onScaleUpdate` to detect  both scales and drag

Comment: @pskink Sounds like a creative idea. Question is, how do you distinguish between drag and scale in `onScaleUpdate`?

Comment: one finger drag?

Comment: @pskink works remarkably well. Thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw how did you distinguish between both?

Comment: `ScaleUpdateDetails.pointerCount` if it's `1` its handled as a drag, if it's '2' its handled as a scale.`ScaleUpdateDetails.focalPoint` is used (abused?) to determine the distance moved. Slightly hackish, but it does it...

Comment: that's right, but it is done on purpose: if you add both `onScaleUpdate` and `onPanUpdate` you will be warned that you should use `onScaleUpdate` only, as it contains all the data to get drag / pan info

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Draggable widget and DragTaregt to drop it in. it is useful and better than creating draggable from scratch. [check this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzA4c4QHZCY)

Comment: oh I got your point now, so you are trying to do something similar to zooming in with 2 fingers, right?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately `Draggable` and `DragTarget` ain't of much use here, because the drag and scale should only be recognized and then be handled by the `CustomPainter`, which then draws a different part of the viewport.

Comment: Yes. The idea is to use a two fingers pinch gesture to zoom/scale and a single finger fling to scroll.